# What is this UI element on OS X?

Tags: mac-os-x

[image]

Do it have any name to call this little thing?

Comment: if its changing images some call it a carousel. If it's an area for a large static image it's often called a hero photo. But in my experience it tends to be more descriptive relative to the design- the "primary", "first", "top", but YMMV.

Comment: Also can you be a bit clearer about what you're referring to? I assumed that you were pointing to the image.

Answer (score 8):

it's a status bar. it's not specific to osx, all browsers have one.

it used to show the url of hovered links, status of requests, etc and then some add-ons/plugins started using it to show information.

Recently it's been reduced to a something like a tooltip in most browsers (it only appears on mouse over links or when something is loading, etc).

Answer (score 6):

This is a **status bar**.

In Cocoa programming you can create this by adding a custom view on the bottom of a window and using a text field to show information as required.

Note that in OS X programming, the "Status Bar" (class `NSStatusBar`) refers to the the rightmost portion of the system-wide menu bar, with all the little icons, the clock, spotlight and so on. User-facing copy however uses "Status Bar" as a term for a horizontal area on the bottom of windows that contains auxiliary information (e.g. link URLs in Safari, or item counts and sizes in the Finder).